# AWS Single Instance Tomcat SSL

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to setup a Apr SSL Connector on my EC2 tomcat instance but it's not working, I don't know why.

I have valid certificate and public key files. Apr module is installed, I've added port 8443 to my EC2 instance's security group but when I'm trying to access the link https://myapp-env.elasticbeanstalk.com:8443/ the page is not available.

I've added the following configuration to tomcat's server.xml:

```
<Connector 
    port="8443" 
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
    maxThreads="200" 
    scheme="https" 
    secure="true"
    SSLEnabled="true" 
    SSLCertificateFile="/etc/ssl/certs/myapp.crt" 
    SSLCertificateKeyFile="/etc/ssl/certs/myapp.key"
    clientAuth="optional" 
    sslProtocol="TLSv1" />
```

Tomcat's log doesn't show any error message, it's exactly the opposite:

```
Oct 24, 2014 1:51:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014)
Oct 24, 2014 1:51:50 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler "http-apr-8080"
Oct 24, 2014 1:51:51 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler "ajp-apr-8009"
Oct 24, 2014 1:51:51 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler "http-apr-8443"
Oct 24, 2014 1:51:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2083 ms
Oct 24, 2014 1:51:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 24, 2014 1:51:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.55
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

[image: Port 8443 added to security group]

Comment: From the screenshot, looks like your beanstalk app is inside VPC. does your load-balancer have a public IP?

Comment: Yes, it's inside a VPC. Where can I check if the load balancer have a public ip?

Comment: simply ping  myapp-env.elasticbeanstalk.com if this returns a private IP, it has private IP. Or, go to EC2 area in AWS console, in the left menu, select load balancers, select your load balancer in the right pane, select the load balancer. under details, check the schema. If it is "internal", it is not public.

Comment: I've just noticed that the title of the thread is "Single instance" but since I've a Load Balancer, it's not Single but Multiple instances. Maybe it was making this question a little confusing...

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk creates a load balancer even for single instance setups. I actually prefer to have SSL certificates on Load balancer than on the EC2 instance itself even if it is not a beanstalk app. This way, I can leave the fixes for heart bleed like bugs to Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually easier than I thought, far easier! I've found the appropriate documentation in:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ssl-server-cert.html

In short, having the certificate and private key, in a Linux AMI, you must run the following commands:

```
sudo yum install apr.i686
sudo yum install mod_ssl
sudo yum install tomcat-native.x86_64
aws configure (enter your aws account data here)
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name yourAliasHere --certificate-body file://certificate.crt.pem --private-key file://private.key.pem
```

It's mandatory to use `file://` notation. After that, just go to your Elastic Beanstalk, Configuration, Load Balancing and set `Secure listener port` and `SSL certificate ID` (which you've just uploaded) fields then Save.

[image]